# Swift. Polish current Time

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

My task is to println current time but in polish language. If I do it now it will be for example: Dzisiaj, 17:39. I can do this with Today, 17:39 PM, but I don't know how to do this with my polish letters.

Comment: your task can be accomplished by using polish-localization for the date formatter.

Comment: Thank you very much. Maybe u know how to do this, where the name of date is under the number of time in Storyboard in TableViewCell as titleLabel.text? I used to this code:
'var date = NSDateFormatter()
        date.dateStyle = .LongStyle
        date.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
        date.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
cell.textLabel.text = "\(date.stringFromDate(NSDate()))"'

Comment: If you want them on separate lines, you'd probably have separate labels, modifying the date formatter for each, and you'd get just the time for one label (e.g. using formatter with `formatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle` and `formatter.dateStyle = .NoStyle`) and just the date for the other (e.g., `formatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle` and `formatter.dateStyle = .LongStyle`). In terms of using two labels on the cell, you can use the `textLabel` and `detailsTextLabel` of the standard cell, or you can create your own custom cell with whatever labels you want.